# Why kubernetes pod fails to run docker image

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I create a simple executable binary file `program` that runs forever:

```
// pseudocode
while (true) {
    print("Sleeping")
    sleep(seconds(1));
}
```

Then I dockerise this program using such `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM debian:10
ADD program /
ENTRYPOINT ["/program"]
```

Then I build and push docker image to a global repository:

```
docker build -t docker:5000/program .
docker push docker:5000/program
```

Then I create a `deploy.yaml` file for this program to be run on a kubernetes pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
 name: program
 namespace: my_namespace
spec:
 containers:
  - name: program
    image: docker:5000/program
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    command: ["echo", "SUCCESS"]
```

Finally, I start the program on kubernetes:

`kubectl create -f deploy.yaml`

However, the `kubectl describe pods -n my_namespace program` reports:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                 From                         Message
  ----     ------     ----                ----                         -------
  Normal   Scheduled  27m                 default-scheduler            Successfully assigned 
mariusl/ingress to mma7-standard5-ime
  Normal   Created    26m (x4 over 27m)   kubelet, mma7-standard5-ime  Created container 
ingress
  Normal   Started    26m (x4 over 27m)   kubelet, mma7-standard5-ime  Started container 
ingress
  Normal   Pulling    25m (x5 over 27m)   kubelet, mma7-standard5-ime  Pulling image 
"docker:5000/program"
  Normal   Pulled     25m (x5 over 27m)   kubelet, mma7-standard5-ime  Successfully pulled 
image "docker:5000/program"
  Warning  BackOff    2m (x117 over 27m)  kubelet, mma7-standard5-ime  Back-off restarting 
failed container
```

Which, in my interpretation means, that the program fails to get executed and gets repeatedly restarted. **Why can this happen?**

Comment: can you add complete output of describe command should give more details like whats exit code etc on the logs ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pod is configured with `command: ["echo", "SUCCESS"]` which will overwrite the `ENTRYPOINT ["/program"]` and hence, your container will only `echo SUCCESS` and terminate immediately.

Note that in [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/), `command` will overwrite `entrypoint` in Docker container and `args` will overwrite `cmd` in Docker container.

You can remove the line `command: ["echo", "SUCCESS"]` and the pod will be up and running!

Answer (score 1):

When you override the default Entrypoint and Cmd, these rules apply: [read here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#notes)

> 1) If you do not supply command or args for a Container, the defaults defined in the Docker image are used.
>
> 2) If you supply a command but no args for a Container, only the supplied command is used. The default EntryPoint and the default Cmd defined in the Docker image are ignored.
>
> 3) If you supply only args for a Container, the default Entrypoint defined in the Docker image is run with the args that you supplied.
>
> 4) If you supply a command and args, the default Entrypoint and the default Cmd defined in the Docker image are ignored. Your command is run with your args.

Answer (score 0):

Your container executes echo "SUCCESS" and terminates, see 
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#notes

`command` in kubernetes overrides `entrypoint` in docker. But this does not explain why the container is failed.